# Process terminated with status 127 while compiling in code blocks

Tags: g++

I installed codeblock in ubuntu and try with a helloworld c++ program with the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

and when I tried to compile, I have got:

```
g++ -Wall -fexceptions -g  -c /home/benoie/Desktop/helloworld/main.cpp -o obj/Debug/main.o
/bin/sh: 1: g++: not found
Process terminated with status 127 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
0 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

Why my program is getting this error code?

Answer (score 4):

To compile, you must, first, install a compiler. You can install `g++` with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install g++
```

To run this command, enter in terminal, and paste this.